# How to remove en from my site urls?

Tags: url, language

After recovering joomla site from failed upgrade and from corrupt backup i at least got it to display something but now all my pages by default point to /index.php/en/ and because its pointing to "en" folder all my template images and site images not showing. It automatically fills in when trying to access website. Any idea how to remove /en/  ?

Here is what i tried:
disabled language filter -- i get error 500
play around with url rewriting -- i get error 404

My previous setup used to be like this:
/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Was the site multi-lingual before this? It sounds like English is set as the primary but that another language is possible also enabled. That is why the en shows up.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to set non-friendly SEF URLs. I have a multilingual website too and I had your same problem.
Do as following: Go to `Plugins -> Language Filter` and set `Yes` to: Remove the prefix from default language. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out my self.
Switching to non friendly sef URLs fixed my problem. 
You can do this from Global Configuration.

Comment: Non-SEF URL'S look horrible though :/

Comment: It is hard to share a page on facebook or others without SEF URL. Because they ignore the address after ? character.